# Salesforce Community - Can we use cookies to only show a visitor a popup once?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, community, cookies

I have a client with a Salesforce Community website who wants to have a pop-up on the homepage, but they only want it to pop up one time per user. This is before they login, so I'm thinking what I'd need to do is drop a cookie on their computer so I know that they already saw the pop-up. Is this possible? Does anyone have any better ideas to make this happen? Thanks!

Comment: once per visit/session? once in  a lifetime?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use either [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to remember this sort of information.

Edit: To explain further, you'd create a custom component, and place it within your community somewhere. This component would check to see if the notification has already been displayed (via cookie or a key in storage), and if not, display a modal and set the flag so future visits won't trigger the modal.

Comment: But how will you access/set these when the Community login page loads? One approach I could think of is to embed a VF page/lightning component on the Community Login page and upon initialization set/access the cookies. Is that what you are recommending?

Comment: @JayantDas Yes, you'd need a way to display the modal anyways, so a Lightning Component would be ideal here. It can just check if there's a cookie/key, if not, display the message and set the cookie/key.

Comment: Yep I had thought the same, I think it will be good to add that information here in your answer to detail out a bit?

Comment: @JayantDas Fair enough. Edited.

Comment: Thanks :) +1 for detailing it out.