# How to track the browsing history of the visitor for my community site? Please help

Tags: javascript, community, community-builder

I need to see whatever the visitor clicked or done over my community site. So , I researched and found out that it can be done via cookies, but not sure how to implement it. Can anyone please help or suggest. Thanks a ton for the help in advance!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SFSE. Please take a [tour] and read [ask]. Could you please share with us something that you have already tried? It's not exactly a duplicate but maybe this question would show you a proper direction: [Salesforce Community - Can we use cookies to only show a visitor a popup once?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258187/salesforce-community-can-we-use-cookies-to-only-show-a-visitor-a-popup-once)

Comment: Hi  
@PrzemysławDługoszewski-Tamoń , Since I mentioned I couldn't find how to do it so how will I mention what I have tried? I have only found that we can do it through cookies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following for the base level reporting. You can try using other webanalytical tools integrated with your sites. However, it is better to use google one.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_google_analytics_setup.htm&language=en_US&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F&type=5

For flow level user tracking the following reports will help you.

Flow level reporting

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_g_a_track_user_flow.htm&type=5